# magento2: checkout process translastion

Tags: magento2, shipping, language, germany

[image]

1) I'm using `github.com/splendidinternet/Magento2_German_LocalePack_de_DE` language pack. However  the `de_DE.csv` was missing the translation for `See Our Shipping Policy`. I added it manually, but that didn't translate anything.

2) I edited `pub/static/frontend/.../de_DE/Magento_Shipping/template/checkout/shipping/shipping-policy.html` (to see if anything changes)-> I changed `See Our Shipping Policy` to `Our Shipping Policy` -> my german Store View displayed `Our Shipping Policy`.

3) Now again I added the translation for `Our Shipping Policy` into `app\i18n\splendid\de_DE\de_DE.csv`  -> nothing gets translated

info: everything else in `de_DE.csv` gets translated !

How can I translate `Our Shipping Policy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the js translation, after changing the text, **we may need to delete `js-translation.json` under `pub/static`**- `pub/static/frontend/.../de_DE/`.
And then **run static content deploy again.**

Comment: I just run static content deploy -> now it's working !    I don't know why

Comment: Did you delete `js-translation.json`?

Comment: No I didn't.  'pub/static/frontend/.../de_DE/js-translation.json' is there, it was created newly (file date changed)

Comment: Ah! I may know the reason, this is because `Our Shipping Policy` is the new text, not exist in `js-translation.json` before. So, we need only run static content deploy. I will check and let's you know.

Comment: You can change the new translation for `Our Shipping Policy`, `Our Shipping Policy 12344`. And run the static content again. This translation will affect?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know we had to delete `js-translation.json`. For future troubleshooting I will take this into account

Comment: Everithyng is working now. I just added the row `Our Shipping Policy,Versandhinweise` into `appt/i18n/splendid/de_DE/de_DE.csv` -> german Store View displays "Versandhinweise" now.    info: fullpage cache is disabled

Comment: Tomorrow, I will check the case - delete or not js translation json file. And then, I will confirm.